# Visual C++: find symbol references without project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, pdb-files

I have an exe, which is built using Visual Studio C++ compiler and linker, but without VS project. (The build process is automated using ANT.)

Is there a chance to *Find All References* to a symbol **just using the exe, its pdb and map file**?

Unfortunately, the map file obviously contains the place of definition only.
And using the context menu function *Find All References* (even from within debugging, having all symbol information), just can search "Entire Solution", "External Sources", "Current Project", "Open Documents",
but not "currently debugged exe".

Or is there a chance to **reconstruct a VS project from a pdb + map**, since the source file paths are contained in the pdb?
Then I could search in this project afterwards.

Comment: How do you debug you exe ? By attaching to the running process or opening it as a project ? And do you have the source files ?

Comment: @nick: I attach to the process. And yes, I have the sources, but the structure and preprocessor switch handling is complex. So simply adding all sources to a project does not produce a working project (but is indeed an idea to identify *potential* references).

Comment: Try this, if you haven't: Start VS, select 'Open Project' and select the Exe. This will create a new VS Project, which you can then debug. I have only ever done this to step through some simple code, so i don't know exactly what else you can all do with this. Adding the Sources might work, though.

Comment: @nick: I did. However even when breaking within a function and seeing the callstack, *Find All References* for the current function (in "Entire solution") only shows the current definition and **not even the direct caller** (only occurences in current file, and also such lines that are not part of the current target code e.g. due to preprocessor switch). Switching to search in "Current project" finds nothing. Poor.

Comment: Ah, right. That's all i got then, sorry :(

Comment: Are you able to open the source files in visual studio?

Comment: @MinxinYu-MSFT: Yes.